# python-taking part of the text stored within a combo box

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt

I have a combo box on a form that I created. This combo box displays an ID and a name together. I am writing the contents of the combo box to a database. So far it writes correctly when I use this piece of code

```
self.ui.residentComboBox.currentText()
```

Now what I want to be able to do is pull only the ID from the combo box instead of the ID and the name together. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the form of the output?  Is it a tuple with `(ID, name)` or a string with `"ID name"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `self.ui.residentComboBox.currentText()` returns a string, and the ID is just the first word, you can do this:

```
self.ui.residentComboBox.currentText().split()[0]
```

which splits the string into a list of words (separated by whitespace) and then the `[0]` gives the first item in that list.

For example:

```
t = "3426523 askew chan"
print t.split()
#['3426523','askew','chan']
print t.split()[0]
#'3426523'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this really did help me a lot! I couldn't be more grateful.